# Need help with a Scheduled Path after Owner Change for a record

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, scheduled-job

I have an Object with OWD as Private.

I have a flow which updates the status on the records of this object as overdue once due date is passed.

- I have used a scheduled path in Record-triggered flow to check if the record status is completed or not after 14 days of due date.
- It runs perfectly but there is a catch in case the owner of the record assigns this record to another user.
- Now, this user has basically lost the access to this record and the scheduled path in the flow is failing saying that the user doesn't have the access to update this record. I understand this is because the scheduled job was added in queue with the previous owner of record but I want the record to still be updated.

If I use a record triggered flow with condition as Owner is Changed, even then the flow runs as the previous owner only.

- Is there any way I can make it to run as new owner?
- Or have the job scheduled as the new owner after owner on the record is changed?
- What would be the right approach to achieve this?

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Answers to first two bullets are NO; [Related doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5)